# IF statement including VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a way to do an IF cell says (this) then VLOOKUP here, IF cell says (thiselse) then VLOOKUP different area.

Might be a super obvious way to do this, so far have this:

Pretty simple but not working

```
Sub categoryVLOOKUP()

'IF col D says STAR then enter VLOOKUP formula into column K
'IF col D says SUN then enter other VLOOKUP formula into column K

Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STARSUN")
For lRow = 2 To LastRow
    If sht.Cells(lRow, 4) = "SUN" Then
        sht.Cells(lRow, 10).Formula = _
            "=VLOOKUP(A3&G3,OF_MOON!A:D, 4,0)"
    Else

    End If

    If sht.Cells(lRow, 4) = "STAR" Then
        sht.Cells(lRow, 10).Formula = _
            "=VLOOKUP(A3&G3,OFWORLD!A:D, 4,0)"
    Else

    End If
Next lRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is getting the formula for multiple cells that is the struggle, I would recommend R1C1 formatting:

```
Sub categoryVLOOKUP()

'IF col D says STAR then enter VLOOKUP formula into column K
'IF col D says SUN then enter other VLOOKUP formula into column K

Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow as long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STARSUN")
For lRow = 2 To LastRow
    If sht.Cells(lRow, 4) = "SUN" Then
    sht.Cells(lRow, 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(R[1]C[-8]&R[1]C[-1],OF_MOON!RC:RC[3], 4,0)"

     ElseIf
     If sht.Cells(lRow, 4) = "STAR" Then
     sht.Cells(lRow, 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=VLOOKUP(R[1]C[-8]&R[1]C[-1],OFWORLD!RC:RC[3], 4,0)" 

End If

Next lRow
End Sub
```

I think this train of thought should get you started. Remember that R1C1 has to be done in reference to the active cell that the formula will go in. I may need to check the rules for referring to new sheets but again, this should get you on the right line :) hope it helps

**EDIT :** Also, I believe you do need to set LastRow
I have added to the code

```
Dim LastRow as long
```

and

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am not familiar with R1C1 - I am relatively new to VBA and learning slowly.

Comment: No problem, I was new not too long ago :) R1C1 is a way that vba can reference cells from the 'current cell'. so R[1]C[1] means 1 row along and 1 column down from the current. if you entered a formula in cell A1 using R[2]C[2] it would refer to cell C3.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that will be a great tip for the future! I ended up solving my own problem by just creating a master sheet with all the data in it, rather than two separate ones. Thanks anyway for your help & tips :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing definition and value of `LastRow`.

Use `option explicit` at the beginning of your modules to enforce variable declaration. Or simply Tools -> Options -> check Require Variable Declaration. It will be done automatically.

Also I do not understand why you would even use VBA for this. Can't you just use formula

`=IF(cell="SUN",1st vlookup, if(cell="STAR", 2nd vlookup,NA())`

Also I suggest using INDEX + MATCH instead of VLOOKUP.

And 3rd "also": you are hardcoding the key you will be looking up for: `A3&G3`. Thus You will get max of 3 values from your actions: Whatever is associated with `A3&G3` in OF_MOON sheet or in OFWORLD sheet or `#N/A`.

Comment: Hi Zaptask, because I have a long list of data, that is added to often, so I cant write a single lookup for each individual line. So it is more 'If column D says SUN at any point then VLOOKUP this sheet, if column D says STAR at any point then VLOOKUP this other sheet. Not specific cells

Comment: In such a case I suggest using Excel tables (I don't know how you feed your data into the system). Even if at the end of the day you still want to stick to VBA I still would suggest using 1 formula instead of selecting 1 of 2 in VBA. I think the former is more redeable and it itself containts all the logic. By using VBA you are hiding some logic from the user.

Comment: I tried using your simple Excel formula, however it returns #N/A. I have no preference for VBA, just all the Excel formula I was entering were failing.

Comment: If in cell J3 you enter =IF(D3="SUN",VLOOKUP(A3&G3,OF_MOON!A:D, 4,0),IF(D3="STAR",VLOOKUP(A3&G3,OFWORLD!A:D, 4,0))) you get NA? You need to have something in column A in sheets OF_MOON or OFWORLD that corresponds to concatenation of A3 and G3. If you are concatenating numbers then you end up having a string which won't get vlookuped from other sheets if they have numbers. In such a case you can either convert the numbers to strings as well or use (A3&G3)*1 or value(A3&G3) instead of A3&G3.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It wasn't working so I have creating a different sheet that contains the data from both the previous sheets I was trying to VLOOKUP from. I think it was something to do with one of the cells I was looking up had numbers while the other had words, I got a #VALUE error at one point. I don't know, think I was doing too much so compiled a master sheet with all the info. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the result as below

```
Sub categoryVLOOKUP()
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STARSUN")
    For lRow = 2 To LastRow
        If sht.Cells(lRow, 4) = "SUN" Then
            Range("K" & lRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A" & lRow) & Range("G" & lRow), Worksheets("OF_MOON").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)
        ElseIf sht.Cells(lRow, 4) = "STAR" Then
            Range("K" & lRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A" & lRow) & Range("G" & lRow), Worksheets("OF_MOON").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```