# Include #NA values from VLookup loop with an If-condition

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have code, which uses the Vlookup function to insert values from a certain column in WS_B into WS_A if values in two other columns in those worksheets match. So if WS_A.Range("$D$1:$D$700") value x matches a value in WS_B.Range("$D$13:$D$700"), then the value from WS_B.(P:P) will be pasted into WS_A.(T:T).

However, if the result of Vlookup is #NA, then the whole row from WS_B, where Vlookup result is #NA, should be copied at the end of WS_A.

```
    Dim rngToWS_A         As Range
    Dim rngfromWS_B       As Range
    Dim rngCelToWS_A      As Range
    Dim rngCelfromWS_B    As Range
    Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set TargetWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    Set rngToWS_A = TargetWorksheet.Range("$D$1:$D$700")
    Set rngfromWS_B = ActiveSheet.Range("$D$13:$D$700")

    For Each rngCelToWS_A In rngToWS_A.Cells
        If Trim(rngCelToWS_A) <> "" Then
            For Each rngCelfromWS_B In rngfromWS_B.Cells
                If UCase(Trim(rngCelToWS_A)) = UCase(Trim(rngCelfromWS_B)) Then
                    rngCelToWS_A.Cells(, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngCelToWS_A, ActiveSheet.Range("D13:P700"), 13, False)

                 **'HERE SHOULD BE THE IF CONDITION FOR FOUND #NA VALUES AND COPYING THE ROW TO WS_A**   
                       
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rngCelfromWS_B
        End If
    Next rngCelToWS_A
```

Unfortunately, I can't bring my head around on how to include the if-condition. It should be like a mix of [this: "How to VLOOKUP get #N/A value in VBA?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555728/how-to-vlookup-get-n-a-value-in-vba) and [this:"IF statement including VLOOKUP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765662/if-statement-including-vlookup).

Comment: Use `Application.Vlookup` and test if the result is an error.

Comment: Should it be something like this `If blabla Then blabla Elseif IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngCelToWS_A, ActiveSheet.Range("D13:P700"), 13, False)) Then CopyRow`?

Comment: `IsError(Application.Vlookup(....))`... no `WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: Use this Syntax,, `Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngCelToWS_A, ActiveSheet.Range("D13:P700"), 13, False)` ☺

Comment: @RajeshS - no, that will *not* work... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup).

Comment: @BigBen,, it works,, I've used few times,, this is the correct command sequence, plzz try once.

Comment: @RajeshS - no....

Comment: @BigBen,, this will trap #N/A error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218920/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-bigben).

Comment: As mentioned in comments, use `Application.Vlookup` and `IsError`... see the linked duplicate, but use the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/9245853), not the accepted one.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it. I got Vlookup to work, however I cannot copy the right #NA rows.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the revised code you're trying?

Comment: @BigBen I posted another question, since this one has been closed as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218031/copy-the-line-where-vlookup-loop-results-in-na-index-problem