# Copy the line where VLOOKUP Loop results in NA (index problem)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

My code looks up values in one worksheet A in another worksheet B, and inputs data from a column in B if the values in A and B match.

However, I am trying to copy those lines, where Vlookup returns #NA to the end of A data. The way I do it though, the for loop remains at the first index and copies an n-amount of lines with the first index content.

```
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = TargetWorksheet.Cells ' Use all cells on the sheet
    LastCol = Last(2, rng) ' Find the last col
    lastRowM = TargetWorksheet.Cells(TargetWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngToA         As Range
    Dim rngfromB       As Range
    Dim rngCelToA      As Range
    Dim rngCelfromB    As Range

    Set rngToA = TargetWorksheet.Range("$D$1:$D$700")
    Set rngfromB = ActiveSheet.Range("D13:D700")

    For Each rngCelToA In rngToA.Cells
        If Trim(rngCelToA) <> "" Then
            For Each rngCelfromB In rngfromB.Cells
                If UCase(Trim(rngCelToA)) = UCase(Trim(rngCelfromB)) Then
                    rngCelToA.Cells(, LastCol - 2) = Application.VLookup(rngCelToA, ActiveSheet.Range("D13:P700"), 13, False)
                    ElseIf IsError(Application.VLookup(rngCelToA, ActiveSheet.Range("D13:P700"), 13, False)) Then
                        'index rngCelfromB
                         ActiveSheet.Rows(rngCelfromB.Row).Copy Destination:=TargetWorksheet.Cells(lastRowM + 1, 1)
                         lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rngCelfromB
        End If
    Next rngCelToA

    Set toCelToA = Nothing
    Set fromB = Nothing
    Set rngCelToA = Nothing
    Set rngfromB = Nothing
    Set rngCelCelToA = Nothing
    Set rngCelfromB = Nothing
```

Here is the code for the Last()-funtion:

```
    Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
   'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
   ' 1 = last row
   ' 2 = last column
   ' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just off the cuff, I think you could use a 2d array to stuff the matched values into instead of copying as found, once the data is in a 2d array, you can write it back out to wherever you like in whatever order you like (walk across, or walk down, or even walk diagonally (but that would be silly)).

The point is, you can control how and where the data goes a lot better this way vs finding the data you want and immediately having to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Yeah, no idea what you mean. I only started using VBA last week.